# Spark: Update file

Tags: apache-spark

I have a file with a list of pairs of strings. The first pair represents an id, the second pair a value.

```
// saving
List<Tuple2> l = new ArrayList<>(0);
JavaRDD<Tuple2> rddL = javaContext.parallelize(l);
JavaPairRDD<String, String> rddPair = rddL.mapToPair(t -> t);
rddPair.saveAsTextFile(collection+".txt");

// loading
JavaPairRDD<String, String> loadedCollection = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(javaContext.objectFile(collection+".txt"));
```

At some points, I need to add new lines or update entries. Therefore, I load the file, create an JavaPairRDD, but they are immutable, thus I cannot add or delete or change.

What is the best practice to do this? Do I need to delete the old file and save a new one everytime I want to change something?

Comment: If you have a lot of writes you may wanna consider using some database like Cassandra or HBase.

Comment: More or less. Spark is a batch processing system and is not designed for fine grained updates. It is not even related to immutability.

Answer (score 0):

The RDD itself does not contain any data.
It only hold the information about how to calculate new data from the loaded data (i.e the lineage).
The RDD is immutable, and in order to change the data it represents - you need to create another RDD from it, and apply the required transformations.

> What is the best practice to do this? Do I need to delete the old file
>   and save a new one everytime I want to change something?

Unfortunately the answer is yes.

You can't load specific entries from the file into a RDD object, and then save only these changes.